# asio::io_context::run_one() with while()

Tags: c++, boost, asio

Why do we need `while` loop, when using `asio::io_context::run_one()` in the following code? What if we don't use `while` loop, like below?

```
size_t numberOfHandler = sock.io_service().run_one();

void set_result(optional<error_code>* a, error_code b)
  {
    a->reset(b);
  }

template <typename MutableBufferSequence>
  void read_with_timeout(tcp::socket& sock,
      const MutableBufferSequence& buffers)
  {
    optional<error_code> timer_result;
    deadline_timer timer(sock.io_service());
    timer.expires_from_now(seconds(1));
    timer.async_wait(boost::bind(set_result, &timer_result, _1));
    optional<error_code> read_result;
    async_read(sock, buffers,
        boost::bind(set_result, &read_result, _1));

    sock.io_service().reset();
    while (sock.io_service().run_one())
    {
      if (read_result)
        timer.cancel();
      else if (timer_result)
        sock.cancel();
    }
    if (*read_result)
      throw system_error(*read_result);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use while loop to process all handlers to throw exception when timeout elapsed and data could not be read within this timeout.

The situation where `async_wait`'s handler is executed before `async_read`'s handler means that socket could not read data in 1 second.

```
1. run_one is called
2. handler passed into async_wait is called
3. timer_result is set
4. else if (timer_result) is processed
5. sock.cancel() is called [ cancel() queues handler with error code !! 
       which indicates that read operation was aborted]
6. handler passed into async_read is queued
```

handler passed into `async_read` was queued, but when it is called? It can be called only by `run_one`. If this handler is not called, `read_result` cannot be set. So, how do you want to signal the situation where data cannot be read for some timeout? `read_result` can be set only by calling handler inside `run_one`. That is why you need to process `run_one` inside loop to call handler which set `read_result` optional with error code which indicates aborted read operation.